# Solving PHP memory leaks

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, memory-leaks

I have a PHP script that runs indefinitely long (infinite main event loop) processing a stream of incoming tweets from Twitter and storing them to MySQL.  However, I can't seem to get its memory usage under control.  I've found 3 ways to measure memory usage:

- `memory_get_usage()` - Reports about 4.0 MB
- `memory_get_usage(true)` - Reports about 7.5 MB
- `exec("ps -o rss -p " . getmypid(), $memOutput);` - Reports a linearly increasing number that quickly grows into the hundreds of MB in 60 minutes or less, and continues eating up memory until the script is forcibly terminated.

My questions:

1) What's the practical difference between these three measures?

But mainly:

2) What does it mean if the first two are relatively constant, but the 3rd method is wildly out of control like this?

FWIW, I'm using PHP 5.3 with Zend Framework 1.x and a lot of Zend_Db activity.  Script runs under the CLI SAPI.  Zend_Db_Profiler is not being used.  I also have a second infinitely-running script that doesn't use the database at all, and memory usage is constant.  So it seems to be database-related, perhaps the MySQL extension my PHP setup is using, or maybe Zend_Db.  I've taken great pains within my own code to avoid caching objects carelessly, although I haven't done this with Zend's code itself.

I've tried making my script call `gc_enable()`, and running `gc_collect_cycles()` periodically, but this doesn't help.

Any ideas?

***Edit*** I intend to profile this code as soon as I can, but meanwhile I've noticed that even my scripts that don't touch the DB are also leaking memory.  But they do so at a much slower rate that only becomes apparent when comparing memory usage over the course of several days.

Comment: And what steps have you already taken in order to reclaim memory after you don't require objects anymore?

Comment: First, I'm avoiding objects where possible by using arrays to transiently store my data.  But regarding objects (such as the table rows that Zend_Db returns), I'm not doing anything special to reclaim their memory.  My understanding is that when they go out of scope (i.e. when the method ends), and when no references to those objects are being retained any more, they are then eligible for reclaiming via PHP's garbage collection.  I'm not retaining any references.  But I realize Zend_Db might be.

Answer (score 2):

Well I cannot point you to the exact answer here because you need to do the profiling yourself. From what you're saying it seems to point Zend's DB layer, however you cannot be sure unless you profile this. ;)

On UNIX/Linux (and I hope you are running PHP the right way - the UNIX/Linux way:D) there are some very useful tools for profiling such apps on the **system level** and checking **instantiation and memory consumption** within the PHP app.
  You can use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/) to get some info, something like:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind --dump-instr=yes -v --instr-atstart=no /usr/sbin/apache2 -X
```

Note that Valgrind is a [suite of tools](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html) and here we're using the 'callgrind' tool - it

> provides all the information that Cachegrind does, plus extra information about callgraphs

This will create a `callgrind.out` file or a set of them I cannot remember.
Anyway you can now use [Kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) to visualize the gathered information:

```
kcachegrind callgrind.out
```

you will no see a visualization of calls and the percentage of memory a certain part of your app uses. Something like:
[image: Wordpress memory profile]

You can also try some of the other tools in the Valgrind suite like [Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck) to see

> all reads and writes of memory and calls to malloc/new/free/delete

I first learnt about Valgrind when trying to profile my Linux server. Then I researched a bit and it turned out that it is a very good tool to profile PHP apps... There is [a very good talk on this here](http://talks.php.net/show/digg/). I used some of the examples from there. Check it out!

And after you profile your app, please come back with information on what was it, or what do you see and etc. I will be very interesting to analyze this. Hope this helped. ;)

EDIT:
  I now recall that I missed some stuff. :D 
You can also try using [APD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) wich is a zend extension and [could also provide useful information](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apd.examples.usage.php). I haven't personally used it but there are some good examples on the Internet.

Another option is [Xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php) - the Hierarchical Profiler. You can use this to [gather different metrics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xhprof.examples.php). In the end a combination of these tools should be used. How and why is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Borislav for the pointers.  I haven't had a chance to try them, but I will when I get a chance.  Meanwhile I've rewritten my scripts so the database-related portions are called as separate short-lived processes.  This effectively solves the memory issue.

Comment: It's still puzzling to me why PHP's user-land memory usage functions show steady and predictable values, while only the memory usage as shown by external processes (e.g. `ps` on the command line) is what's out of hand.  This makes me think it might not be the user-land PHP code at all, but maybe lower-level issues with PHP or some extensions I'm using.  It'll be very interesting to profile the code with the tools you mentioned.

Comment: @curtisdf Yes, indeed. It would be very interesting to profile that.
Would you be willing to share the data afterwards? It will not contain any code anyway. Also it could really be some external entity.
Anyway PHP is a scripting language and long-running scripts have always been a issue because of its design.
One of the other things to try is "Async PHP" - [react as an example](http://reactphp.org/). It could be the solution to long-running scripts on an event basis.

Comment: I'll gladly post my findings here, although since the problem is averted for now and I have a lot on my plate, I'm not sure when I may get to it.  Here's hoping by within the next few days or this coming weekend.